# Prevent any form of ESC from closing a magit buffer

Tags: magit, evil

I'd like to be able to prevent Magit from closing a buffer when I press <kbd>ESC</kbd>. I also want to prevent my `evil-escape-mode` sequence (<kbd>kj</kbd>) from closing it as well.

Running <kbd>C-h k ESC</kbd> gives

```
<escape> runs the command magit-mode-bury-buffer, which is an
interactive compiled Lisp function in ‘magit-mode.el’.
It is bound to <escape>, <normal-state> <escape>, <menu-bar> <Magit> <Quit Magit>.
```

I'm not sure what the best approach is. Can I unbind `magit-mode-bury-buffer` from all of those commands? If so, how?

Comment: Your best bet would be to unbind these keys from `magit`'s map (probably `magit-mode-map` from `eval-after-load` (or some other macro if you use something like `use-package`)). I don't know much about `evil-escape-mode` (or `evil` in general, so I have no idea what approach it takes, but my guess is that it attempts to look up what's bound to `ESC`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can simply unbind the key after loading `evil-magit`. Something to the effect of

```
(require 'evil-magit)
(evil-define-key* evil-magit-state magit-mode-map [escape] nil)
```

should work.

Comment: Thank you. A combination of that and `(setq evil-escape-excluded-major-modes (list 'magit-status-mode 'magit-refs-mode 'magit-log-mode)))` to prevent `evil-escape-mode` worked.

Answer (score 1):

This binding is established in `evil-magit-mode-map-bindings` from the `evil-magit` package, which I'll assume you use. I on the other hand don't use that or Vi key bindings in general, but from the little I believe to know about it, it seems weird that <kbd>ESC</kbd> would be bound to `magit-mode-bury-buffer`. You should probably open an issue in the projects issue tracker.

---

*Update*: The behavior that you don't want was intentionally added in [#14](https://github.com/emacs-evil/evil-magit/issues/14). It can be reverted using:

```
(evil-define-key* evil-magit-state magit-mode-map [escape] nil)
```

Comment: Thanks. Looks like it was added as a feature [here](https://github.com/emacs-evil/evil-magit/issues/14).

Comment: Please ask on that issue how to undo it (or learn how to do it from the evil documentation) and then post that here as an answer.